# MySQL UPDATE on first column

Tags: sql, mysql

I have many tables which their ID columns' name is different but column name subjected to update stays same.

For example

```
Columns:

fooID | x | y | UPDATEME | t | ..
barID | a | UPDATEME | b | ..
bazID | UPDATEME | m | l | ..
```

As you can see, the ID column is always first but column names changing. And I want to update `UPDATEME` column regardless the ID columns name.

```
UPDATE `UPDATEME` WHERE `FIRST_COLUMN` = #
```

How can I accomplish this? I am aware of `ORDER BY column_order` syntax but I can't use this in `WHERE` clause.

Comment: It isn't obvious what your problem is. Can't you just build the SQL with the correct id column dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

There is no SQL syntax to do that. But you can access DB metadata (INFORMATION_SCHEMA) to generate your update sentences.

Something like this:

```
select 
   concat(
       'update ',
       table_name, 
       ' set updateme=1212 where ', 
       column_name, 
       '=12123;'
  )
  from information_schema.columns 
 where ordinal_position = 1;
```